# What is Relationship between ciphertext quotient and polynomial degree in RLWE?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, lwe, ring-lwe

In Ring Learning with Errors problem, the size of the ciphertext quotient $q$ decides the size of the polynomial degree $n$ or vice versa. In other words, rlwe problem is hard only when the polynomial degree is set in comparison to the quotient. However, I am not sure what is the relationship between the values of the two parameters?

Can someone explain to me or point me to some resource?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean? It seems to me you might be talking about *module* LWE, over a ring $R$ that has some non-trivial rank as an abelian group. But I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Hey @Mark I edited the question I am talking about polynomial degree which is also called ciphertext in some literature. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a "relationship" between these two parameters, due to what is known as *modulus switching*.
Roughly, given an LWE instance $\bmod q$, one can change it into an LWE instance $\bmod p$ at relatively little cost, for a wide variety of $p$.
There are many results along these lines, but I will describe one from [Worst-case to Average-case Reductions for Module Lattices](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/090.pdf).

> Let $\psi$ be some probability distribution on $\mathbb{T}_{R^\vee}$, and $s\in(R^\vee_q)^d$ be a vector. We define $A^{(M)}_{q,s,\psi}$ as the
> distribution on $(R_q)^d × \mathbb{T}_{R^\vee}$ obtained by choosing a vector a $s\in(R_q)^d$ uniformly at random, and $e \in \mathbb{T}_{R^\vee}$
> according to $\psi$, and returning $(a, \frac{1}{q}\langle a, s\rangle + e)$.

> **MLWE**: For an integer $q \geq 2$ and a distribution $\Psi$ over a family of distributions over $K_\mathbb{R}$. The decision version of
> the Module Learning With Error problem $M-LWE_{q, \Psi}$ is as follows: Let $s \in (R^\vee_q)^d$ be uniformly random and
> $\psi$ be sampled from $\Psi$ ; The goal is to distinguish between arbitrarily many independent samples from $A^{(M)}_{q, s, \psi}$, and the same number of independent samples from $U(R^d_q, \mathbb{T}_{R^\vee})$.

This is more general than RLWE, and reduce to RLWE when $d = 1$.
The family of distributions $\Psi_a$ are a certain elliptical Gaussian distribution, see section 2.3.

Anyway, the modulus switching result is theorem 4.8.
Here, $N = nd$ is the "total dimension" of the MLWE instance.
Setting $n = 1$ recovers the case of RLWE, that you are interested in.

> Let $p, q \in [2, 2^{N^{O(1)}}
> ]$ and $\alpha, \beta ∈ (0, 1)$ such that $\beta \geq \alpha \max(1, \frac{q}{p})n^{1/4}N^{1/2}\omega(\log_2 N)$
> and $\alpha q \geq \omega(\sqrt{\log(N)/n})$. There exists a polynomial time reduction from $M-LWE_{q,\Psi_\alpha}$ to $M-LWE_{p,\Psi_\beta}$.

This is all to say that you can reduce from an arbitrary modulus $q$ to another arbitrary modulus $p$, at the cost of inflating the noise rate from $\alpha\mapsto \frac{q}{p}\alpha\sqrt{N}\omega(\log_2 N)$. This isn't *totally* for free (there is an additional $\sqrt{N}$ factor), but given that the moduli $q, p$ are typically small polynomials in $N$, the cost you pay is relatively small in comparison to parameter sizes.

As a result, there really isn't a relationship between solely the ciphertext modulus (as it is typically called, not the ciphertext quotient) and the dimension, as any relationship *also* needs to take into account the size of the error distribution.

As for how to actually set all of these things, people typically feed their parameters into the [LWE Estimator](https://lwe-estimator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which gives some bit security estimate for each particular parameter set.

Comment: Thanks for the response yes I do understand that you can switch from mod $q$ to mod $p$ when $p<q$ at no reduction to security but is that true also when $p>q$, according to my understanding and practice that would reduce the security for a fixed $N$?

Comment: In other words, if I take two RLWE samples, with the same $N$ and have an error sampled from the same distribution, but the ciphertext modulus of the first sample is $q$ and the other is $p$ , where $p>q$ , will they have same security level? I believe the RLWE sample with modulus $q$ will have a higher security level.. and that's what I want to understand why is that

Comment: When changing moduli, it is best to think about things in terms of the quotient of $\sigma/q$, e.g. *relatively* how big $\sigma$ is compared to $q$. It doesn't sound like you are talking about this, which can cause issues. In particular, if you increase $q$ without simultaneously changing $\sigma$, the quotient $\sigma/q'$ shrinks, reducing security.  If you decrease $q$ without simultaneously changing $\sigma$, the quotient $\sigma/q'$ grows, increasing security. To determine precisely how much the security is (estimated to) change, use the LWE estimator.

Comment: okay got it so there is no contrived equation that gives a relationship of $N,q,\sigma$, and security level?

Comment: There is, but it is easiest to use LWE estimator. Roughly, the contrived equation is $\mathsf{seclevel}(N, q, \sigma) = \min_i (f_i(N, q, \sigma)$, where each $f_i(N, q, \sigma)$ describes a particular attack on (R)LWE. For more on each $f_i$, you can read the [NewHope Specification, section 4.2](https://www.newhopecrypto.org/data/NewHope_2020_04_10.pdf). NewHope (was) the most popular RLWE-based cryptosystem submitted to NIST's PQC standardization. It did not advance to the final round, as NIST has preferred MLWE and "plain LWE" over RLWE.